# Update one database table value from another based on recently updated records

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database-administration

I have a scenario where i have to update record in database table from another database table based on recently updated record.

if record is new insert statement  will fire
if record is updated Update statement will fire

here the problem is we don't know number of table return by query
as well as column name.

here is code

```
DECLARE @RowsToProcess  int
DECLARE @CurrentRow     int
declare @tablenames varchar(100)
DECLARE @sampleTable TABLE(RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), tablename varchar(100),last_user_update datetime)
insert into @sampleTable SELECT [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),last_user_update
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE    database_id = DB_ID('DATABASE')
select * from @sampleTable
SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT
print @RowsToProcess
SET @CurrentRow=0
WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1
    SELECT @tablenames= tablename from @sampleTable
        WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow
   print @tablenames
   EXEC('INSERT INTO '+ 'SM_' + @tablenames +'  SELECT * FROM  '+@tablenames + 'Where flag = NULL' )
END
```

Comment: are you using sql server?

Comment: Consider using a trigger: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms189799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use [triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). SQL Server triggers can fire on insert, on update, on delete or instead of insert, etc.

You may get started using [this lesson](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/an-introduction-to-triggers-part-i)